# Combining Java Enum and Generics

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am trying to design a piece of code using generics and enums. I wish to get the enum using a primitive integer as well as it must hold a string. I have many enums, and so I implemented them with an interface so as to remember to override the public `toString()`, `getIndex()` and `getEnum()` methods. However, I am getting a type safety warning, any idea how to get rid of it and why it is happening?

```
public interface EnumInf{
    public String toString();
    public int getIndex();
    public <T> T getEnum(int index);
}

public enum ENUM_A implements EnumInf{
    E_ZERO(0, "zero"),
    E_ONE(1, "one"),
    E_TWO(2, "two");

private int index;
private String name;
private ENUM_A(int _index, String _name){
    this.index = _index;
    this.name = _name;
}
public int getIndex(){
    return index;
}
public String toString(){
    return name;
}
// warning on the return type:
// Type safety:The return type ENUM_A for getEnum(int) from the type  ENUM_A needs unchecked conversion to conform to T from the type EnumInf
public ENUM_A getEnum(int index){
    return values()[index];
}
```

Comment: FYI, declaring `toString()` in the interface is useless.  All `Object`s already declare that.  All you need to do is override it in the implementing class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface EnumInf<T extends EnumInf<T>> {
    public int getIndex();
    public T getEnum(int index);
}

public enum ENUM_A implements EnumInf<ENUM_A> {
    ... the rest of your code
```

(As I noted in the comments, declaring `toString()` in the interface is pointless.)

Comment: Thanks, can u explain a bit how it get rids of the warning?

Comment: I think it's because in my code, when you say `ENUM_A implements EnumInf<ENUM_A>`, the compiler can figure out right there that `T` is the same as `ENUM_A`, so the return type of the method is the same.  In your original code, apparently it doesn't have enough info to figure that out.  Maybe that's because the return type of the implementing method doesn't have to be the same as the interface method, because of covariance.  But I really don't know for sure.

Comment: you are using a raw type

Comment: @newacct Please explain: (1) who is "you", and (2) what is the raw type you're referring to?

Comment: @newacct OK, I made a change.  Maybe that's what you were referring to?  I can't tell.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be "public interface EnumInf<T implements EnumInf<T>>"?

Comment: @billjamesdev Because that's not legal Java.  Don't ask me why the language syntax is the way it is.

Comment: Figured as much.  Thanks for the response!